# How to Toggle in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to click a button (or in my example below, a link) and toggle between 2 blocks of content to essentially go from displaying content to editing content.

I have the following snipits of code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.show {display:block;}
    input.hide {display:none;}
</style>

<a href="#">edit</a> <!--not sure what my jquery should look like to do toggling-->
<div class="show" id="d-01-on">Some content</div>
<input class="hide" id="d-01-off" name="d-01" value="Some content" />
```

Thanks for helping.

[see [How to Streamline and Compress Repetitive jQuery Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159735/how-to-toggle-within-a-content-list-in-jquery) for expansion to this techique]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy with jQuery just add the following JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#button').on('click', function() {
        $('#d-01-on').toggle();
        $('#d-01-off').toggle();
   });
})
```

And it will work with your current markup and css code.

Comment: if you have a moment @Skatox could you take a look at my follow-on problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159735/how-to-toggle-within-a-content-list-in-jquery ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

to show and hide an element using jquery is done as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="d-01">content</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$.("#d-01").toggle(); //toggles display so if shown then hides, if hidden then shows;
$.("#d-01").show();  //shows div
$.("#d-01").hide();  //hides div
```

Comment: also, to trigger this from a hyperlink, wrap the jquery code in a function definition, then give your <a> tag an onclick property with the function's name as its argument

Comment: Cool, thanks @mr_lewjam...giving it a try now. I'll post back in a few moments.

Comment: Thanks @mr_lewjam. I worked through this until I saw Skatox's suggestion below. I then tried that one and got it working really quick. So I am going to mark Skatox as the answer, but I really appreciate your suggestion and I am sure I could get it to work with more effort.

Answer (score 1):

This will toggle visibility of both elements:

```
function handleClick() {
  $('div.show').toggle();
  $('input.hide').toggle();
}
```

Then of course your class names will be wrong.  You could use IDs instead.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @ChrisMiller. I am going with Skatox below as I got it running really quickly.