# How to Streamline and Compress Repetitive jQuery Code

Tags: jquery

I want to click a link and toggle between 2 blocks of content, within a list of content, to essentially go from displaying content to editing content.

I have the following snipits of code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.show {display:block;}
    input.hide {display:none;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#d-01').on('click', function() {
            $('#d-01-on').toggle();
            $('#d-01-off').toggle();
            $('#d-01-off').focus();
        });
         $('#d-02').on('click', function() {
            $('#d-02-on').toggle();
            $('#d-02-off').toggle();
            $('#d-02-off').focus();
        });
        $('#d-99').on('click', function() {
            $('#d-99-on').toggle();
            $('#d-99-off').toggle();
            $('#d-99-off').focus();
        });
   })
</script>

<a href="#" id="d-01">edit</a>
<div class="show" id="d-01-on">Some content</div>
<input class="hide" id="d-01-off" name="d-01" value="Some content" />

<a href="#" id="d-02">edit</a>
<div class="show" id="d-02-on">Some content</div>
<input class="hide" id="d-02-off" name="d-02" value="Some content" />

<a href="#" id="d-99">edit</a>
<div class="show" id="d-99-on">Some content</div>
<input class="hide" id="d-99-off" name="d-99" value="Some content" />
```

This works, but I want to make my jquery/javascript code more dynamic and not hard coded. My MySQL table rows will grow over time and I don't want to have to keep editing my script.

Is it possible to re-write the jquery code to dynamically handle the ID's rather than having to create individual and redundant `on('click', function()`'s?

Thanks for helping.

[see [How to Toggle in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158276/how-to-toggle-in-jquery) for my initial question to this problem]

Comment: Looking for some expert help in jQuery if you have a moment. Thanks.

Comment: Answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309322/how-to-take-hard-coded-repetitive-jquery-syntax-and-condense-to-be-dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understanded what you want but here i go:

First add a div to wrap each repetive section of the HTML markup, in this example I added a class called **content-wrapper** to add the jquery click event easier:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <a href="#" id="d-01">edit</a>
    <div class="show" id="d-01-on">Some content</div>
    <input class="hide" id="d-01-off" name="d-01" value="Some content" />
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <a href="#" id="d-02">edit</a>
    <div class="show" id="d-02-on">Some content</div>
    <input class="hide" id="d-02-off" name="d-02" value="Some content" />
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <a href="#" id="d-99">edit</a>
    <div class="show" id="d-03-on">Some content</div>
    <input class="hide" id="d-03-off" name="d-03" value="Some content" />
</div>
```

Then i modified the JS to the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.content-wrapper a').on('click', function() {
            $(this).siblings().toggle();
            $(this).siblings('input').focus();
        });
   })
</script>
```

The JS adds a event to each anchor (a tag) inside the divs of content-wrapper, then when it is clicked, it checks for its siblings (the tags next to it like: div.show and the input) and toggles them. I added a filter in the second siblings to get only the input of the clicked anchor and focus it.

I didn't test it but it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Skatox. I'll look at it later tonight as I need to attend to a different matter right now. Basically, what I need is to have the javascript/jquery section work off passing some parameter to it to indicate the div id for toggling. Right now my table has 25 rows. I don't want to hardcore 25 instances of the common jquery code (like I am doing in my example above) because as soon as my client adds a new row to the db my query will not have thatid coded and covered in the jquery section. hope that makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Ok, try at night and let me know if it worked. Currently the solution i gave you is dynamic, you can add as many rows as you want and it will work.

Comment: Thanks @Skatox. Had to work on a flooded basement all night so I did not yet get a chance to look at this. I will do so in a couple hours. Thanks for helping.

Comment: My page(s) work so cool using your solution but only as it is hardcoded. Somehow I need to be able to produce the jquery/javascript in a dynamic fashion. I can let you look at the page if that helps you and if you have time to peek at it. Can you PM me if you are able to assist? Thanks Skatox!