# How To Take Hard-Coded/Repetitive jQuery Syntax and Condense to be Dynamic

Tags: jquery

I have a web page with some jQuery code. Right now I am hardcoding my jQuery syntax to accommodate for updates to 7 rows in a DB Table and also to anticipate growth of about 3 more rows. But I don't want to check my app daily to see if the DB Table has grown beyond 10 rows and then have to add more hardcoded jQuery syntax.

Can anyone help me take my jQuery and condense it to be truly dynamic -- thus removing the hardcoded nature of it and enable it to handle any number of rows? Thanks.

```
<style type="text/css">
div.icons {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    height:24px;
    width:30px;
}
div.content {
    height:24px;
}
div.show {
    display:block;
}
div.hide {
    display:none;
}
input.textbox {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:300px;
}
input.submitButton {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
img.button {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#b-001').on('click', function(){
        //$('#d-001-off').hide('slow');$('#d-001-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-002-off').hide('slow');$('#d-002-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-003-off').hide('slow');$('#d-003-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-004-off').hide('slow');$('#d-004-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-005-off').hide('slow');$('#d-005-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-006-off').hide('slow');$('#d-006-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-007-off').hide('slow');$('#d-007-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-008-off').hide('slow');$('#d-008-on').show('slow');

        $('#d-001-on').toggle();
        $('#d-001-off').toggle();
        $('#d-001-off-focus').focus();
    });
    $('#b-002').on('click', function(){
        $('#d-001-off').hide('slow');$('#d-001-on').show('slow');
        //$('#d-002-off').hide('slow');$('#d-002-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-003-off').hide('slow');$('#d-003-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-004-off').hide('slow');$('#d-004-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-005-off').hide('slow');$('#d-005-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-006-off').hide('slow');$('#d-006-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-007-off').hide('slow');$('#d-007-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-008-off').hide('slow');$('#d-008-on').show('slow');

        $('#d-002-on').toggle();
        $('#d-002-off').toggle();
        $('#d-002-off-focus').focus();
    });
    $('#b-003').on('click', function(){
        $('#d-001-off').hide('slow');$('#d-001-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-002-off').hide('slow');$('#d-002-on').show('slow');
        //$('#d-003-off').hide('slow');$('#d-003-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-004-off').hide('slow');$('#d-004-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-005-off').hide('slow');$('#d-005-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-006-off').hide('slow');$('#d-006-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-007-off').hide('slow');$('#d-007-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-008-off').hide('slow');$('#d-008-on').show('slow');

        $('#d-003-on').toggle();
        $('#d-003-off').toggle();
        $('#d-003-off-focus').focus();
    });
    $('#b-004').on('click', function(){
        $('#d-001-off').hide('slow');$('#d-001-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-002-off').hide('slow');$('#d-002-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-003-off').hide('slow');$('#d-003-on').show('slow');
        //$('#d-004-off').hide('slow');$('#d-004-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-005-off').hide('slow');$('#d-005-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-006-off').hide('slow');$('#d-006-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-007-off').hide('slow');$('#d-007-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-008-off').hide('slow');$('#d-008-on').show('slow');

        $('#d-004-on').toggle();
        $('#d-004-off').toggle();
        $('#d-004-off-focus').focus();
    });
    $('#b-005').on('click', function(){
        $('#d-001-off').hide('slow');$('#d-001-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-002-off').hide('slow');$('#d-002-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-003-off').hide('slow');$('#d-003-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-004-off').hide('slow');$('#d-004-on').show('slow');
        //$('#d-005-off').hide('slow');$('#d-005-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-006-off').hide('slow');$('#d-006-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-007-off').hide('slow');$('#d-007-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-008-off').hide('slow');$('#d-008-on').show('slow');

        $('#d-005-on').toggle();
        $('#d-005-off').toggle();
        $('#d-005-off-focus').focus();
    });
    $('#b-006').on('click', function(){
        $('#d-001-off').hide('slow');$('#d-001-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-002-off').hide('slow');$('#d-002-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-003-off').hide('slow');$('#d-003-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-004-off').hide('slow');$('#d-004-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-005-off').hide('slow');$('#d-005-on').show('slow');
        //$('#d-006-off').hide('slow');$('#d-006-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-007-off').hide('slow');$('#d-007-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-008-off').hide('slow');$('#d-008-on').show('slow');

        $('#d-006-on').toggle();
        $('#d-006-off').toggle();
        $('#d-006-off-focus').focus();
    });
    $('#b-007').on('click', function(){
        $('#d-001-off').hide('slow');$('#d-001-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-002-off').hide('slow');$('#d-002-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-003-off').hide('slow');$('#d-003-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-004-off').hide('slow');$('#d-004-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-005-off').hide('slow');$('#d-005-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-006-off').hide('slow');$('#d-006-on').show('slow');
        //$('#d-007-off').hide('slow');$('#d-007-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-008-off').hide('slow');$('#d-008-on').show('slow');

        $('#d-007-on').toggle();
        $('#d-007-off').toggle();
        $('#d-007-off-focus').focus();
    });
    $('#b-008').on('click', function(){
        $('#d-001-off').hide('slow');$('#d-001-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-002-off').hide('slow');$('#d-002-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-003-off').hide('slow');$('#d-003-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-004-off').hide('slow');$('#d-004-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-005-off').hide('slow');$('#d-005-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-006-off').hide('slow');$('#d-006-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-007-off').hide('slow');$('#d-007-on').show('slow');
        //$('#d-008-off').hide('slow');$('#d-008-on').show('slow');

        $('#d-008-on').toggle();
        $('#d-008-off').toggle();
        $('#d-008-off-focus').focus();
    });

    // 2 extra for growth
    $('#b-009').on('click', function(){
        $('#d-001-off').hide('slow');$('#d-001-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-002-off').hide('slow');$('#d-002-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-003-off').hide('slow');$('#d-003-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-004-off').hide('slow');$('#d-004-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-005-off').hide('slow');$('#d-005-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-006-off').hide('slow');$('#d-006-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-007-off').hide('slow');$('#d-007-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-008-off').hide('slow');$('#d-008-on').show('slow');
        //$('#d-009-off').hide('slow');$('#d-009-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-010-off').hide('slow');$('#d-010-on').show('slow');

        $('#d-009-on').toggle();
        $('#d-009-off').toggle();
        $('#d-009-off-focus').focus();
    });
    $('#b-010').on('click', function(){
        $('#d-001-off').hide('slow');$('#d-001-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-002-off').hide('slow');$('#d-002-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-003-off').hide('slow');$('#d-003-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-004-off').hide('slow');$('#d-004-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-005-off').hide('slow');$('#d-005-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-006-off').hide('slow');$('#d-006-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-007-off').hide('slow');$('#d-007-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-008-off').hide('slow');$('#d-008-on').show('slow');
        $('#d-009-off').hide('slow');$('#d-009-on').show('slow');
        //$('#d-010-off').hide('slow');$('#d-010-on').show('slow');

        $('#d-010-on').toggle();
        $('#d-010-off').toggle();
        $('#d-010-off-focus').focus();
    });
})
</script>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="icons"><a id="b-001"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="Edit button" class="button" title="Edit" /></a></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="show" id="d-001-on">Northside</div>
        <div class="hide" id="d-001-off"><input class="textbox" id="d-001-off-focus" name="d-001-off" maxlength="50" type="text" value="Northside" />&nbsp;<input src="images/go.png" alt="Go button" class="submitButton" onclick="$('#action').val('update');$('#location').val('001');" title="Update" type="image" />&nbsp;<a href="/seminars/admin/index.php"><img src="images/cancel.png" alt="Cancel button" class="button" title="Cancel" /></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="icons"><a id="b-002"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="Edit button" class="button" title="Edit" /></a></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="show" id="d-002-on">South Lawn</div>
        <div class="hide" id="d-002-off"><input class="textbox" id="d-002-off-focus" name="d-002-off" maxlength="50" type="text" value="South Lawn" />&nbsp;<input src="images/go.png" alt="Go button" class="submitButton" onclick="$('#action').val('update');$('#location').val('002');" title="Update" type="image" />&nbsp;<a href="/seminars/admin/index.php"><img src="images/cancel.png" alt="Cancel button" class="button" title="Cancel" /></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="icons"><a id="b-003"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="Edit button" class="button" title="Edit" /></a></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="show" id="d-003-on">East Wing</div>
        <div class="hide" id="d-003-off"><input class="textbox" id="d-003-off-focus" name="d-003-off" maxlength="50" type="text" value="East Wing" />&nbsp;<input src="images/go.png" alt="Go button" class="submitButton" onclick="$('#action').val('update');$('#location').val('003');" title="Update" type="image" />&nbsp;<a href="/seminars/admin/index.php"><img src="images/cancel.png" alt="Cancel button" class="button" title="Cancel" /></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="icons"><a id="b-004"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="Edit button" class="button" title="Edit" /></a></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="show" id="d-004-on">West Wing</div>
        <div class="hide" id="d-004-off"><input class="textbox" id="d-004-off-focus" name="d-004-off" maxlength="50" type="text" value="West Wing" />&nbsp;<input src="images/go.png" alt="Go button" class="submitButton" onclick="$('#action').val('update');$('#location').val('004');" title="Update" type="image" />&nbsp;<a href="/seminars/admin/index.php"><img src="images/cancel.png" alt="Cancel button" class="button" title="Cancel" /></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="icons"><a id="b-005"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="Edit button" class="button" title="Edit" /></a></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="show" id="d-005-on">Lobby</div>
        <div class="hide" id="d-005-off"><input class="textbox" id="d-005-off-focus" name="d-005-off" maxlength="50" type="text" value="Lobby" />&nbsp;<input src="images/go.png" alt="Go button" class="submitButton" onclick="$('#action').val('update');$('#location').val('005');" title="Update" type="image" />&nbsp;<a href="/seminars/admin/index.php"><img src="images/cancel.png" alt="Cancel button" class="button" title="Cancel" /></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="icons"><a id="b-006"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="Edit button" class="button" title="Edit" /></a></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="show" id="d-006-on">Ground Floor</div>
        <div class="hide" id="d-006-off"><input class="textbox" id="d-006-off-focus" name="d-006-off" maxlength="50" type="text" value="Ground Floor" />&nbsp;<input src="images/go.png" alt="Go button" class="submitButton" onclick="$('#action').val('update');$('#location').val('006');" title="Update" type="image" />&nbsp;<a href="/seminars/admin/index.php"><img src="images/cancel.png" alt="Cancel button" class="button" title="Cancel" /></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="icons"><a id="b-007"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="Edit button" class="button" title="Edit" /></a></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="show" id="d-007-on">TBD</div>
        <div class="hide" id="d-007-off"><input class="textbox" id="d-007-off-focus" name="d-007-off" maxlength="50" type="text" value="TBD" />&nbsp;<input src="images/go.png" alt="Go button" class="submitButton" onclick="$('#action').val('update');$('#location').val('007');" title="Update" type="image" />&nbsp;<a href="/seminars/admin/index.php"><img src="images/cancel.png" alt="Cancel button" class="button" title="Cancel" /></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="icons"><a id="b-008"><img src="images/add.png" alt="Add button" class="button" title="Add" /></a></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="show" id="d-008-on">Add a new location</div>
        <div class="hide" id="d-008-off"><input class="textbox" id="d-008-off-focus" name="d-008-off" maxlength="50" type="text" value="" />&nbsp;<input src="images/go.png" alt="Go button" class="submitButton" onclick="$('#action').val('insert');$('#location').val('008');" title="Add" type="image" />&nbsp;<a href="/seminars/admin/index.php"><img src="images/cancel.png" alt="Cancel button" class="button" title="Cancel" /></a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Maybe start using classes instead of incremental IDs..

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment @FabrícioMatté. My "incremental IDs" relate to the ID column in the DB table, which helps me ensure I update the correct row in the database.

Comment: Yes, I meant not to remove them, but to add classes to facilitate the selectors. Sec while I take a deeper look into the structure.

Comment: Threw up a jsfiddle to look closer at it: http://jsfiddle.net/ZKXQB/

Comment: Since you are doing this for a table consider using row and column indexes instead of the id's. It is very scalable.

Comment: Can you be a little clearer @JayBlanchard or maybe dumb-it-down a bit so I understand what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: If you could set up a fiddle with your code it would be easier to demonstrate once we saw the action that you're desiring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6mSgm/)** — Sorry to say this, but your code is poor.

Following is the jQuery replacement without changing any of your HTML, except for wrapping the "Add a new location" row with `<div class="content-wrapper"></div>`.

```
$('.icons a').on('click', function(){
    var $contentWrapper = $(this).closest('.content-wrapper');
    var $siblings = $contentWrapper.siblings('.content-wrapper');
    $siblings.find('.hide').hide('slow');
    $siblings.find('.show').show('slow');
    $contentWrapper.find('.show').toggle();
    $contentWrapper.find('.hide').toggle().find('.textbox').focus();
});
```

Don't forget to wrap the above jQuery in `$(function(){ ... });` so that it only executes once the DOM is ready.

Comment: :) I know it is @Coby -- that's why I thought I would post here and get some "expert" help ;)

Comment: Oh and thanks for catching the missing <div> I actually discovered it too when I was preparing this question.

Comment: I am going to give your answer a try and post back shortly. Appreciate the help !

Comment: Ah, no success @Coby. I removed my "hardcoded" jquery syntax and simply added your code verbatim. I made no other changes. My toggling stopped working.

Comment: Make sure the jQuery is wrapped in `$(function(){ ... });` so that it executes only after the DOM is ready. See http://jsfiddle.net/6mSgm/1/

Comment: @H. Ferrence: I'm guessing you missed the big bad **DEMO** link to jsFiddle at the top of my answer.

Comment: Ha ha..yep -- missed your DEMO link @Coby. My Bad. Looked at your jsFiddle and yours works. Need to tweak my web page a bit. I'll post back on selecting your as the answer in a few moments...

Answer (score 0):

I can only agree with Coby.

Figured it might be fun to try my hand at it. But I'm not sure how the stuff is supposed to work. Since I'm not supposed to link JS Fiddle you should just go with Coby's code.

There's quite a bit of improvement you can do to the markup and JS.

Are you including the input-fields in the code for some kind of JS-free fallback? Otherwise you could add them using JS and not have quite so much markup. One of many possible changes.

Comment: Why are you not supposed to link to a jsfiddle?

Comment: When including a jsFiddle link in your answer, but no code in your answer itself, SO will prevent you from submitting the answer. The idea is to also include a snippet of the code solution in your answer.

Comment: Didn't know, didn't plan for it. Got put off ;)

Comment: Awesome @jbn. Aside from the lack of the graphics, the jsFiddle works just as my web page works at the moment. Now all I need to do is figure out how to condense my hardcoded jquery into something more dynamic. I appreciate your assistance in creating a jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ZKXQB